# How can I unregister my user?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm programming a game engine + editor. Not a game. I feel that this site is not for me.
Sorry if this is another off-topic, but I can't find no option nor help to unregister my account.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think I jumped the gun on closing your question.  I'll reopen it.  Engine development is very much a part of game development, although you'll find that a lot of people here are a bit more pragmatic about things and would say that it's going to be hard to compete with the solutions that are already out there for actually making games.

Comment: glad my answer helped, but you might want to reconsider - I noticed Tetrad just re-opened your question. The site *could* be helpful to you in the long run, and it's not like it costs anything to have an account here. :)

Comment: why do you want to delete your account? considering it's not exactly easy to do, and one user won't make much of a difference to any stats...and here's just as good for game engine questions anyway (since they're game development).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SE doesn't make it terribly easy - see [can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account). Be careful to ask them only to delete the gamedev account, presuming you want to keep your SO account.

Comment: Yep, it's hard :) Thanks for your answer!